# Django, serving static files from the STATIC_ROOT when running in runserver?

Tags: django

There's a need to do live debugging in production environment.

Some (bundled) static files are only available at the `STATIC_ROOT` and having trouble accessing it when running `runserver`

Is there a way to access `STATIC_ROOT` when running `runserver`?

Comment: FYI: Using `runserver` in production is a BAD idea. `runserver` is for development purpose. Use `gunicorn`/`uwsgi` for running the server, apache/nginx for serving the static/media contents :)

Comment: @ruddra I guess they are already using a production setup but want to temporarily run the dev server for some reason. @eugene You can install a third party package, such as `whitenoise` to serve static assets.

Comment: I'm running separate `runserver` on the machine. production server runs on nginx/uwsgi